# How to get elements info from a PowerPoint slide with the JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, office365, office365-apps

I'm playing with the new JavaScript Office API, which I think is awesome news. I've been playing with the Excel API and no many problems so far. The thing is that I have one objective with the PowerPoint API that I couldn't reach yet: How to extract all the info from a slide.

I used **[Document.getSelectedDataAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142294%28v=office.1501401%29.aspx)** but I found that only **Office.CoercionType.SlideRange** can be used for PowerPoint, and it only returns a JSON with **id, title and index**.

I'm looking for a way to extract the **objects data** from an specific slide. This may be done by exporting the file and then accessing to the XML file, mapping it to JSON and sending it to our API so we can consume that data later. This option has a huge development cost (sending the entire file).

So the final question is as follows:

**Which is the best method to get a JSON with the data from all the objects placed on a unique slide from PowerPoint?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you that I do not believe you can do this at the moment in PowerPoint via Office.js. One of the downsides to the Office.js library at the moment is that there is not much feature parity between the Office products and PowerPoint is one of the most lacking at the moment.